# Should I use only IndexedDB or both IndexedDB and chrome.storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb, google-chrome-storage

I'm a bit confused here.
I'm making a chrome extension where users can store data (like images and common extension options). What I want to know is what is the best way to store the data?

- Is it only IndexedDB, where both extension options and files can be stored there
- Or using both IndexedDB and chrome storage, where IndexedDB only stores the large files

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since chrome.storage can't store `ArrayBuffer` the most reasonable choice for files is IndexedDB.

The options, assuming it's [a very small object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync), may be stored in chrome.storage.**sync** so the user gets the same options on every device or chrome.storage.**local** if syncing doesn't make sense for your extension or the object is big.

Comment: Got it, options use the old chrome storage.